# Weird height issue on embedded youtube video

Tags: html, css, video, youtube

On this page, I have an embedded youtube video that will (ultimately) be in a container with a variable width. When I put it in without the container, the aspect ratio is fine. When I put it inside the container, the video height stretches way past what would be considered a normal aspect ratio (See screen shot).

[image]

Here is the relevant code:

```
.video-container {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 74.05rem;
    margin-left: 1.1rem;
    margin-right: 1.1rem;
    margin-right: 0;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0; }

.video-container iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; }
```

I referenced this article when doing this, so if there is a better way, someone please shout it out! http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

For reference, this currently sits live at http://www.idealbrandon.com/ksu2

Answer (score 0):

I believe the article you are referring to uses jQuery to achieve the effect you want. This is the script they posted for iframe

```
// Find all YouTube videos
var $allVideos = $("iframe[src^='http://www.youtube.com']"),

    // The element that is fluid width
    $fluidEl = $("body");

// Figure out and save aspect ratio for each video
$allVideos.each(function() {

  $(this)
    .data('aspectRatio', this.height / this.width)

    // and remove the hard coded width/height
    .removeAttr('height')
    .removeAttr('width');

});

// When the window is resized
$(window).resize(function() {

  var newWidth = $fluidEl.width();

  // Resize all videos according to their own aspect ratio
  $allVideos.each(function() {

    var $el = $(this);
    $el
      .width(newWidth)
      .height(newWidth * $el.data('aspectRatio'));

  });

// Kick off one resize to fix all videos on page load
}).resize();
```

http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

Comment: Thanks, but the jQuery technique is only a fall back technique. They describe an HTML/CSS only option above that which I am trying to use. More specifically, regardless of the fluidity of the video, I am most concerned for why it spit out this weird height.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so after doing a little digging and playing, I've determined that it is the padding hack that is causing the problem. Which means that I am just on a hunt for a different solution.

Thanks for looking at this anyways.